# Angular 5 / Sentry error reporting shows error source reference in bundled js

Tags: angular5, sentry

I have applied `Sentry.io` error reporting in an `Angular 5` project using `Raven-js`. Everything works fine and I get the error reports.

The problem is that the reported error location is provided using the bundle.js file references which is very hard to find in the actual project.

For e.g.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
  at e.logOffline (/mem/main.f858f9330b4c0ee7c38e.bundle.js:1:26440)
  at e.phoneOffline (/mem/main.f858f9330b4c0ee7c38e.bundle.js:1:25883)
  at t.handleEvent_12 (/mem/main.f858f9330b4c0ee7c38e.bundle.js:1:488537)
  at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (/mem/vendor.f8004cbd231f87b295e2.bundle.js:1:311586)
  at HTMLAnchorElement.r (/mem/vendor.f8004cbd231f87b295e2.bundle.js:1:666890)
```

Now this reference is not useful to locate the error.

Is there something that I missed in the sentry setup or this is how it actually shows the error?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Sentry can't find your source maps. If your site is public, Sentry will try to get the spurce maps automatically. Otherwise you can upload the source maps yourself.

https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/sourcemaps/

Answer (score 0):

The usage of source maps works out of the box for a **deployed** app. Sentry tries to fetch the source maps through the public internet and thus cannot fetch them on localhost.

If your source maps aren't public (e.g. out of security concerns), then you need to upload them manually like described here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/sourcemaps/availability/#uploading-source-maps-to-sentry .